# display the longest increasing subsequence

Tags: c++, lis

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[]={0,8,4,12,2,10,6,1,9,5,13,3,11,7};
    int b[50],i,j,n,ls[50];
    n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int maxlen=0,end=-1;
    b[0]=-1;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ls[i]=1;
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j] && ls[i]<ls[j]+1)
            {
                ls[i]=ls[j]+1;
                b[i]=j;
            }
        }
        if(ls[i]>maxlen)
        {
            end=i;
            maxlen=ls[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<maxlen<<endl;
    for(int k=end;b[k]!=-1;k=b[k])
    {
        cout<<a[k];
    }
            return 0;
}
```

This was the program I done for finding the longest increasing subsequence. I am getting the length of the subsequence correctly but i am not getting the sequence correctly. I think there may be a problem with the the last for loop which contains the variable `k`, but I cant figure it out. please help me.

Comment: I just ran your code and it printed 5 for the length of the longest increasing sequence. I dont see an increasing subsequence of longer than 2... I think you need to double check your logic for finding the longest sequence first.

Comment: @jlars62 - the "[longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)" problem usually doesn't require the subset to be contiguous.

Comment: @jlars62 `0,2,6,9,13` is a subsequence with length 5. A subsequence doesn't need to be consecutive in the original sequence.

Comment: Your right my bad! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you wrote correct sequence but in reverse order and skipping the first(last) element

You may change the last for to include the first element

```
vector<int> v;
for(int k=end;k!=-1;k=b[k])
{
    cout << a[k] << ' ';
}
```

You may need to store element in something like `std::vector` to reverse it to get correct order

```
vector<int> v;
for(int k=end;k!=-1;k=b[k])
{
    v.push_back(a[k]);
}
reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
for(int x: v) {
    cout << x << ' ';
}
```

http://ideone.com/URPACA